# jQuery validate with single element and rules

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

As part of a larger jQuery validated form I have some inputs only requiring validation on a button press. For example inputting items into a list:

```
<form class="validate">
    // ......
      validated form elements on submit
    // ......

    <select multiple="multiple" id="itemList" size="5"><select>
    <input type="text" id="newItem" name="newItem"/>
    <button type="button" id="addItem">add</button>

    // ......
      validated form elements on submit
    // ......
    <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).on("click", "#addItem", function(e){
       if( $("form.validate").validate({}).element("#newItem") ){
           //Code to add valid item to the list
       }
   });
</script>
```

I don't want to use the input's class as a way to assign the rules as this will mean it will be validated as part of the main form but if i call the validation in the form $([form]).validate({rules..}).element([element]) they are ignored.

The only way I could get this to work was to use rules( "add", rules ) before validation and rules( "remove", rules ) after.

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click", "#addItem", function(e){
        $("#newItem").rules("add", {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2,
            messages: {
               required: "Required input",
               minlength: jQuery.format("Please, at least {0} characters are necessary")
            }
        });

        $("form.validate").validate().element("#newItem");

        $("#newItem").rules("remove");
    });
</script>
```

This however seems quite inelegant so if anyone can tell me where I'm going wrong that would be grand :)

Comment: why you are checking if( $("form.validate").validate({}).element("#newItem") ) if you want to check for if the form is valid or not use $("form.validate").valid() this method returns true or false, the other one returns the validate object.

Comment: @prog-mania At this point I don't need to know if the form in its entirety is valid, I just want to validate the single input that is being used to populate an other element of the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click", "#addItem", function(e){
       var _validateSingleField=$('form.validate').validate().element('#newItem');

       if(_validateSingleField){
           //Code to add valid item to the list
       }
   });
</script>
```